# Cython + OpenSSL: Use bundled libcrypto on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, cython

If python (x64) is installed on windows, libcrypto (part of OpenSSL) is also available as DLL in the installation folder:

```
C:\Python37-x64\
 - python.exe
 - DLLs\
   - ... < many *.pyd and *.dll files >
   - libcrypto-1_1.dll
   - libssl-1_1.dll
```

However, the headerfiles for OpenSSL are not part of the distribution. Therefore I downloaded OpenSSL (https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and installed / extracted it:

```
C:\OpenSSL-v111-Win64\
 - bin\
   - libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
   - libssl-1_1-x64.dll
   - ...
  - include\
  - lib\
```

The python extension is then built with the following args:

```py
Extension('testproj', source=['testproj.pyx'], 
          include_dirs=['C:\OpenSSL-v111-Win64\include'], 
          library_dirs=['C:\OpenSSL-v111-Win64\lib'], 
          libraries=['libcrypto'])
```

This works without any issues, also importing and working with `testproj` does work. However, analysing the running process with `Procmon` shows that both dlls are loaded: The one from `C:\Python37-x64\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll` and also `C:\OpenSSL-v11-Win64\bin\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`. The former is somehow loaded by python itself, while the later is loaded by my extension. According to the file manager both dlls are the same version: 1.1.1c so only one of the two dlls would be required.

Is it possible to build the extension such that the extension also uses the `libcrypto` which is shiped with python?

Some background about why I wonder if it would be possible to use the same DLL:

- Can something unpredictable happen if both DLLs are used?
- The goal is to create a single file executable (using pyinstaller) and adding `libcrypto` twice increases the size of the build.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope this gives some more insight.

Comment: I don't use Windows that often, so I would not trust me, but... To build you need *.lib-files (which are probably in the `OpenSSL-v111-Win64\lib` directory), so the dlls from Python's DLL folder are of no use for building. However, you could use them when loading the extension. Now, the question is why it loads the dll from `C:\OpenSSL-v111-Win64\bin` and not from Python's installation: here is how dlls are found: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by putting the pyd-file into the same folder. How can I do this if i write a package?

Comment: Yea, there are, but I still don't understand how this should be related to my question. The problem is that the wrong `libcrypto`is loaded. Your sugestion with placing my own `*.pyd` file into the DLL directory is not an option because the `*pyd` file is part of a package and I don't know if there is a way to move a file to this directory during `pip install`

Comment: Even if moving the `*.pyd` to the DLL directory would be possible, it would not solve the problem mentioned in the question. The problem is that once the library is loaded as `libcrypto-1_1.dll` and once as `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`. So placing the pyd file in the DLL directory would still load a different libcrypto. The link you provided just helps to adjust the search path, but not the name which is searched for.

Comment: oh... I missed -x64:( You could put a symlink called "libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll" next to pyd, which would point to dll in the Python-folder.